# Orphaned Session Management Records in Database. How to handle the issue? DB Stability Risk

Tags: php, session, cookies, persistent

I have a webapp that uses persistent cookies to allow a user to stay logged it.

I am using the **Improved Persistent Login Cookie** method.
https://www.programering.com/a/MDO0MzMwATA.html 
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29006560/selector-validator-cookies.html

When a user is logging in through the LOGIN form and has asked to be remembered I generate a random `selector` and a random `token` and add these to a table called `Session` in my DB along with the `userID` and other values(IP,time,browser,whaterver). I also set a **cookie** called `KeepMeLoggedIn` with the value `selector:token` and expire in 30 Days.

When the user returns to the site (before or after the **PHP Session/Code Igniter** has expired) I check for `$_SESSION` variable, if none found I look for my `KeepMeLoggedIn` cookie. If the cookie returns a value I check it against my `Session` table to see if the `selector` and `token` match. If they match I reset the `token` and store it back in the DB and `cookie` is updated to the new `selector:token` value and the login process completes.

When a user logs out I destroy the `cookie` and `session` and delete the entry in the DB for the `selector`.

All this is working great except for when a user deleted the cookies manually. The record in my `Session` table is orphaned. In testing my system I ended up with 50+ records in my `Session` table that were from the cookies I manually deleted while testing the logic. Since I manually deleted the cookie the `selector` was not available to the code to be deleted/removed from the `Session` DB.

So here is my question**s**:
1) What is a usable approach to handling these orphaned record?
My first thought is just purge the Session table of any date older then my chosen  expiration date for the `Remember Me` function, either when a user logs in, or in a chron job, or whenever

Are there any other ideas here?

2) Is this a vulnerability in the overall model that can allow a hacker to:

```
create an account on a website
x=1
while x <2
    -> login and ask to be remembered
    -> delete the cookie
do();
```

And end up flooding the website's Session Table till the site is shut down, adding 1,000 and 1,000 of record over time??